# when I select a country I want the id?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-spinner

- I am getting id and name in my spinner from this response,now what I am trying is if user select India from spinner then I want to get id value ,but I am not getting it,following is my response and code,can any one tell me that what is the issue..
- Responce

  ```
  {"search values":
  [
      {"id":"1","name":"India"},      
      {"id":"2","name":"srilanka"}
          ],
          "success":1 
  }
  ```
- for example I’m select india I want result id ==1,

when I’m pass the id I’m getting state list response

```
{"searchvalues":[{"id":"1","name":"Tamilnadu"},{"id":"1","name":"Kerala"}],"success":1}
```

- My code is :

  ```
  country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
      View view, int position, long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String  countryname = country.getSelectedItem().toString();
  StringRequest state=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, D_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {

          try {
              JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray  jsonArray             =jsnobject.getJSONArray("searchvalues");

          distadapter.clear();
           for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

               JSONObject obj= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

           }

          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your spinner ?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353006/transaction-id-set-correctly-but-displayed-only-a-submit-later)

Comment: Is your spinner contains id and name from response or what is lilly you mentioned ?

Comment: try this demo :http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/android-spinnersdropdownlist-tutorial.html#.VooUNjWY4x8

Comment: u jus need to save ur json in an arraylist and then in onitemselected u can get the id by position..simple

Comment: tq for replay @ im adding name(country name) its working fine but when im choose country from drop down ,that moment i need country id value from my response....

Comment: tq Neha Tyagi @ already my responce add to array list , how to get selected coutry id help me

Comment: @RaviTeja is it solved??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to create Getter-Setter class to get Id's and name for 1st JsonObject.

Here is code for Getter-Setter

```
public class SearchValues {

String id, name;

public SearchValues(String id, String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @param name
 *            the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @param id
 *            the id to set
 */
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public String getId() {
    return id;
}}
```

Create a list inside mainActivity like this

```
List<SearchValues> values;
```

And declare inside onCreate Method.

```
values = new ArrayList<SearchValues>;
```

Create AsyncTask to get values of 1st JsonObjects

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
// get values and add these values in list like this
String id = obj.getString("id");
String name = obj.getString("name");
SearchValues val = new SearchValues(id,name);
values.add(val);}
```

After getting these values, add code in Spinner

```
spin_numberPages
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       String id = values.get(position).getId();
                      // here you get ID and now you may do what you want to do with ID.

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing create a custom view of spinner and create a hidden field of id in spinner item and when you select the spinner item get the id from the selected spinner item

Answer (score 0):

Create two  ArrayList for one for name and one for `id` in your class like

```
ArrayList data_json = new ArrayList<SearchValues>();
ArrayList country_name = new ArrayList<String>();   for name
ArrayList country_id = new ArrayList<String>();     for id
```

and get `id` `name` in your Volley Response from `json`

```
   try {
         jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("searchvalues");
         for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
         jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
         data_json value = new data_json();
         value.setName(jsonobject.optString("name"));
         value.setId(jsonobject.optString("ID"));
         data_json.add(value);
         country_name.add(jsonobject.optString("name"));
         country_id.add(jsonobject.getString("ID"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and get id in your `OnItemSelectedListener`

```
ArrayAdapter adapter =
        new ArrayAdapter(getApplication(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.text1,country_name);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
      String cut_code = country_id.get(position);
      String selectedItem = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
  });
 }
```

May be help you

Answer (score 0):

Here pass selected country to check json object if that object contains that city then that object should contain id associated with that city.so take id from it

id=0;

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

             JSONObject obj= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


            if(obj.getString("contry").equals(selected_country))
{
                 id=obj.getInt("id");
break;

         }
```